# Need assistance to remember a way to shorten code in ANSI-C using # signs

Tags: java, c

When I took a class on ANSI-C in my university, I was taught a method to shorten a lot of repeating code. Basically, it's a declaration at the start using the # sign that you can use to assign a name and the code it should replace. Can anyone help me remember what this method was called, and it is possible to implement in Java? I cannot figure out how to search for this on the web, so I thought I'd turn for help here. Thanks!

Comment: Java do not have macros.  In my experience this makes programs written in it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably thinking of [macros](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html).

For example:

```
#define INCREMENT(x) x++
```

However, macros are literally expanded to- meaning unless they're aggressively parenthesised, they can produce unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Be very careful with side effects.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm not good enough to use macros- too many things can go wrong that I just don't bother.

Comment: Macros can be dangerous if you're not *very* careful with operator precedence and side effecdts. An example: https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/42

Comment: These comments would be better directed at the asker- I *know* the danger in using macros.

Comment: @KeithThompson you made a github project for _that_?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Sure, why not? It's not as if GitHub projects are expensive or difficult to set up.

Comment: Macros! That's the name! Can't believe it just flew out of my head, hah. Much appreciated.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have edited the question to include words of caution.

Answer (score 2):

In C you can use the pre-processor with the

```
#define
```

directive which allows you define macros

Java does not have anything like macros, but you can remove repeated code in any modern language using function and procedure calls.

The advantage of function calls (in Java) over C Macros is they enforce type safety, something  to be happy about.

Comment: a #define can be anywhere in C, .h or .c.

Comment: @JoshPetitt point taken, I edited it so it mirrors my intention.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still can't believe I just forgot the term like that.